# Js function passes null to the controller, in the old version

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to wrote a code on an older version of the .net Framework, namely 4.5.2.
I ran into a problem, the ajax code sends an empty request to the controller.

Here is the form and I need to check user Full Name on unique:

```
<div class="register-card">
    <h1>Register the new user</h1>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateUserAsync", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div>
            @Html.Label("FullName", "Enter your full name")
            <input type="text" id="FullName" name="FullName" pattern="^(\w\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)$" onblur="CheckAvailability()" required />
            <span id="message" onclick="ClearMessage()"></span>
        </div>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" /></p>
    }
</div>
```

Here is my js function to checking Full Name:

```
function CheckAvailability() {
    var data = $("#FullName").val();
    var param = data;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/CheckFullNameAsync",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "String",
        data: JSON.stringify(param),
        success: function (response) {
            var message = $("#message");
            if (response) {
                message.css("color", "red");
                message.html("Full name is already exist");
                $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            else {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(param));
                message.css("color", "green");
                message.html("Full name is available");
                $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        }
    });
};
function ClearMessage() {
    $("#message").html("");
};
```

Js function pass the FullName to next controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> CheckFullNameAsync([FromBody]string fullName)
    {
        var isValid = await _service.IsUserExistAsync(fullName);
        return Json(isValid);
    }
```

But the controller receives null.
I think the problem is in the Js function, but I can figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `dataType: "String"`?  That's not [a listed option](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).  And more specifically, all you're sending is a *value* but with no *key*.  So the server isn't able to deserialize the data and determine where the `fullName` value comes from.

Change the type to `'json'` and send the object with the named key for the value:

```
dataType: "json",
data: { fullName: param },
```

Comment: Thank you very much, 
I've tried a lot of options and there's a mistake here!

Answer (score 2):

Dont need to create two variable

```
var data = $("#FullName").val();
var param = data;
```

Just create

```
var param = $("#FullName").val();
```

try this

Check this link.  [it explains your problem well](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/web-api-with-ajax-understand-formbody-and-formuri-attribute/)

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/CheckFullNameAsync",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{"":param},
        //data: { fullName: param },
        success: function (response) {
            var message = $("#message");
            if (response) {
                message.css("color", "red");
                message.html("Full name is already exist");
                $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            else {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(param));
                message.css("color", "green");
                message.html("Full name is available");
                $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        }
    });
```

or this one also

```
$.post('/Home/CheckFullNameAsync', { fullname: param}, 
    function(returnedData){
         console.log(returnedData);
}).fail(function(){
      console.log("error");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
I tried the first case as you described, still null came to the controller.
The second case worked for me, thank you!